# Updating multiple columns in a joins table in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, formbuilder

I'm having a bit of trouble getting my code to work -

I have several models - `Student`, `Course`, and `CourseStudents`, a joins table between the two.  A `Student` can be assigned to multiple `Course`s through the `CourseStudents` model.

### student.rb

```
has_many :courses, :through => :course_students
```

### course.rb

```
has_many :students, :through => :course_students
```

---

Heres some of the working example in the student sign up form.  Let's pretend each student can only sign up for two courses at a time.  This form will return the params `:courses => ["1","2"]` (depending on what was selected, of course).

```
<%= f.fields_for :courses do |course| %>
     <%= course.collection_select(nil, Course.all, :id, :name) %>
     <%= course.collection_select(nil, Course.all, :id, :name) %>
<% end %>
```

This is a problem, because to assign courses to a student, Rails is expecting `Course` objects, not IDs.  I am unsure how to convert these IDs into objects on the fly.

If it is helpful, my `CourseStudents` table is fairly simple.  It has a `course_id` and `student_id` field.  Unfortunately, I do not see how I can go in and iteratively insert a record saying `course_id: 1`, `student_id: 1`, `course_id: 2`, `student_id: 1`.

---

TL:DR;

I need a way to do the equivalent of `Student.first.courses = [Course.find(1), Course.find(2)]` - in other words, pass an object through a selection form instead of an ID, or convert the ID while processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails provides `relation_ids=` method for has_many relations ([doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many)). So you can just assign courses ids to a student.

```
student.course_ids = [1,2]
```

Comment: I really must have had my brain fried - thanks!  Also, if anyone sees this in the future, remember to put `:course_ids => []` in your allowed parameters.